Dynamic in the setting file
In the code below, I want to make it dynamic, for example using models, what should I do so that it is called in the settings file
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'example.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '12345678'

In the code below, I want to make it dynamic, for example using models, what should I do so that it is called in the settings file

You don't. settings are even wrapped in an immutable structure to prevent altering it.
